# ELASTICSEARCH - Aggregations only to the query results

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to first filter the results that contain the values: 33 and chicago in the nested description and door fields

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "data.addresses",
      "inner_hits": {
        "_source": ["data.addresses.direction"],
        "size":100
      },
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "data.addresses.services",
          "inner_hits": {
        "size":100
      }, 
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
              {"match": {"data.addresses.services.description": "chicago"}},
              {"term": { "data.addresses.services.door.keyword": "33"}}
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "data.addresses"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "NAME": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "data.addresses.directions",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I want to get a counter of the results of the query itself about directions field, but it returns a counter for the entire JSON.

How can I do the aggregations only to the query results?

mapping

```
{
  "miguel" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "created_at" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "data" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "addresses" : {
              "type" : "nested",
              "properties" : {
                "description" : {
                  "type" : "text"
                }
                "services" : {
                  "type" : "nested",
                  "properties" : {
                    "banner" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "description" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "output" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "door" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    }                  
                  }
                }
              }
            }  
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "inner_hits" is used to represent the nested documents which result in the query output when we use a nested query. By defining size with-in "inner_hits" the outcome of the aggregation won't be impacted as the aggregation happened over the source of the parent document. Nested docs don't contain any _source, the resulting _source in the inner hits is just the parsed _source of parent doc.That is the precise reason why your query isn't working as expected.

Comment: so if I delete the definition size:100 into inner hits the aggregations would work as expected?

Comment: You need to use combination of nested aggregation + filter + top filter. 
Question: Can you please explain the query condition on which you want to run aggregation on. Based on the query you created i am not sure about the requirement.

Comment: along with that please so share the index mapping as well.

Comment: The objective of the query is to extract the fields that meet the query filter, later I need to count those fields that have the values ​​of the query
I have added the mapping in a summarized way, since it is a JSON with many nested fields and very extensive
I hope this is enough for you